# What is an adjective that means constant with a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, connotation

The context is that the character is lamenting the fact that his employers are watching him in a suffocating way and restricting his freedom

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/incessant

Answer (score 4):

Incessant is almost always used negatively. Relentless is also really good to make something feel overwhelming, as long as the context indicates a bad situation.

Answer (score 2):

[**Interminable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interminable):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> : having or seeming to have no end
> *especially* : wearisomely protracted
> // an *interminable* sermon
>
> // And yet until last month, many here saw the rise of the cartel as an internal matter for the parties in an *interminable* drug war.
> — Kevin Sieff, *Washington Post*, "Mexico’s Jalisco New Generation Cartel blazes a bloody trail in rise to power," 10 July 2020
>
> // Who’s telling them to maintain a safe distance from each other while standing in an *interminable* line?
> — Kevin Sherrington, Dallas News, "Is moving football to the spring really such a bad idea? Like it or not, it’s time to consider the option," 5 July 2020

It could be used in the context of the question in the following way:

> The atmosphere of attention, suspicion, and micromanagement was *interminable*.

Answer (score 2):

You could say he felt dogged by his employers. As an adjective, dogged, as in dogged persistence, dogged pursuit.

From https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dogged

> Definition of dog (Entry 3 of 4)
> transitive verb

> 1a : to hunt, track, or follow like a hound

> dogged her every move

> b : to worry as if by pursuit with dogs : PLAGUE

> dogged by his past failures

> c : to bother or pester persistently

> dogged him about his grades

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your character feels **persecuted**? From M-W:

> **[persecute](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persecute)**: to annoy with *persistent* or urgent approaches (such as attacks, pleas, or importunities)

And from under [*Choosing the right synonym for **persecute***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persecute#synonyms):

> **Persecute** implies a *relentless* and *unremitting* subjection to annoyance or suffering.

Your context:

> The character is lamenting the fact that his employers are watching him in a suffocating way and restricting his freedom, i.e., he is being or feels he is being **persecuted**.